# need to read from a txt file into a dictionary

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary, python-2.7

I have a data file that contains what need to become the keys and entries in a dictionary. I will be reading and writing the entries and reading the keys.  I have found similar things explained elsewhere on stackoverflow but for the life of my cannot make sense of it.  any help is more than welcome!

```
engine oil/filter : 6000
transmission fluid : 48000
timing belt : 96000
other belts : 96000
brake fluid : 48000
air filter : 48000
spark plugs : 96000
rear differential : 48000
```

Above is the data file that needs to be read into a dictionary
below is the dictionary it needs to end up in.

```
service_intervals = {'engine oil/filter' : 6000 , 'transmission fluid' : 48000 , 'timing belt' : 96000 ,
                 'other belts' : 96000 , 'brake fluid' : 48000 , 'air filter' : 48000 ,
                 'spark plugs' : 96000 , 'rear differential' : 48000}
```

what sort of algorithm or functions could i use to make this happen?

EDIT: from sleuthing tells me that something to do with ast.literal_eval may be the best solution, but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `ast.literal_eval`. Just read line by line, `split` on `:`, `strip`, parse the integers, and put the values into the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
with open('some file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split(':')
        my_dict[key.strip()] = int(value)
```

Comment: ok, so just to make sure i actually understand as opposed to copying, line.split will read line by line, while the key, value says that key comes first on the line, then the value is after the ":"?
if so, that makes total sense.  Thanks very much!!

Comment: @gaircity: `split` does not read line-by-line; the `for line in f` reads line by line. For each line, `split` will split it into the part before the `:` and the part after the `:`. That result is then unpacked into the variables `key` and `value`.

Comment: split(':') separates a string into a list of n fields for n-1 colons.  It might actually be better to use line.partition(':').  "for line in f" is actually the part that reads line by line.